# What's the difference between Leiningen and Clojure CLI tools and how should I use them?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm playing around with Clojure recently. The most loved dependency management tool in the Clojure ecosystem is Leiningen to my knowledge. But I also found Clojure has provided [CLI tools](https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli) which probably could replace Leiningen. Due to the limitation of experience in Clojure, I do not quite understand the difference between Leiningen and those CLI tools. I heard those CLI tools is much lightweight, what does it mean? How should I use them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CLI tools are more limited in scope than Leiningen - it's a small tool which you can use to launch a REPL quickly. Combined with `tools.deps.alpha` it can be used to run code and pull in 3rd party dependencies.  You can read more about it [here](https://clojure.org/reference/deps_and_cli).

Leiningen can do all of that, plus:

- create deployment artifacts (uberjars)
- start a REPL server or connect to a running one
- manage mixed projects (for example Clojure + Java or Clojure + Clojurescript)
- run arbitrary tasks in your project
- manage dependencies
- plugin support (linters, deployment tools)
- integrate with Maven

The Lein repository includes a sample project file, [sample.project.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj), which is a bit overwhelming but shows all the things Lein can do.

At this point, Lein is more useful for building applications and libraries - as it has all the features you might need to do that. That said, CLI tools + `tools.deps` is quickly gaining traction and there are projects which add all the missing bits from Leiningen, but you have to combine them yourself.

Comment: this answer is outdated (was true at some point) but not CLI can do all that and super seeds leiningen on most clojure open source projects.

Comment: @andy Interesting - do you have any evidence to back that? Based on the most recent Clojure Survey (2020, https://clojure.org/news/2020/02/20/state-of-clojure-2020) - Lein is used by nearly 90% of respondents, while clj cli is roughly used by 50%. I'd still say, that Lein offers better out of the box experience, even without plugins - especially the uberjar command.

Comment: I agree, I've gone back and forth with this since I wrote that comment, and we're good either way. The only advantage I can still find in CLI is that it integrates figwheel with out of the box and no configs on user part, and also I love the straight-from-github dependency pulling in deps.edn. But it's a simple matter of preference. Thank you for your reply tho, I stand corrected.

Comment: No problem Andy - I hope that eventually deps somehow merges with Lein (for example replaces its dependency management, and makes Leiningen more of a project task runner sort of thing).

Comment: The answer may still be true in some areas. I find this a bit overwhelming https://github.com/EwenG/badigeon

Comment: Yep, I hope that we will see some convergence soon - it must be really confusing for newcomers.